# XPathReader error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, xml, xpath, clob

I am trying to parse data from XML that has been obtained from a `Clob` type. For some reason, I am getting this exception... I can't figure out why. I have obtained the Clob from an oracle database column that contains an `XMLType` value, that is the XML. I have successfully extracted the XML contained from the `XMLType` to a `Clob` type. This is obtained with the following code:

```
xmlBean =  XmlHelper.xPathRead(film.getXmlClob());
```

the `film` object is in the model if you will, and the `getXmlClob()` method returns a `Clob` value that contains the XML I want to parse using XPath. Here is the rest of the code:

**XMLHelper**

```
public static XmlBean xPathRead(Clob xmlClob) {
    XPathReader reader = new XPathReader(xmlClob);
    XmlBean xmlBean = new XmlBean();   // just an entity from the model to store the xml's contents inside

    String filmId = "/IMAGE[1]/@id";
    xmlBean.setFilmId(Integer.parseInt((String) reader.read(filmId, XPathConstants.STRING)));
}
```

**XPathReader**

```
public class XPathReader {
    private String xmlString;
    private XPath xPath;

    public XPathReader(Clob xmlClob) {

        try {
            if ((int) xmlClob.length() > 0) {  
                String s = xmlClob.getSubString(1, (int) xmlClob.length()); // this is a way to cast a CLOB into a STRING
                this.xmlString = s;
              }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    }

    public Object read(String expression, QName returnType) {
        try {
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
            return xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlString, returnType);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? The problem resides in the `evaluate()` method...

**Error message**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.w3c.dom.Node  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown
>   Source)   at helper.XPathReader.read(XPathReader.java:34)     at
>   helper.XmlHelper.xPathRead(XmlHelper.java:325)

Comment: According to the docs, evaluate needs an object or an input source. Could you put an input source instead - xPathExpression.evaluate(new InputSource(xmlString), returnType)

Comment: @Woody, according to this: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html` it needs a `String`...

Comment: True, but that is an XPath, not an XPathExpression which you are using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it from a string anyway.

How about something like this

```
public class XPathReader {
  private XPath xPath;
  private Document doc;

  public XPathReader(Clob xmlClob) {

    try {
        if ((int) xmlClob.length() > 0) {  
            String s = xmlClob.getSubString(1, (int) xmlClob.length()); // this is a way to cast a CLOB into a STRING
            doc = readDoc(s);
          }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
}

public Object read(String expression, QName returnType) {
    try {
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
        return xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, returnType);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Document readDoc(String s)
{
    Document d = null;
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
        d = builder.parse(is);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return d;
}
```

}

I haven't actually tried it and you need better error handling, but it should work ok